# I expect 'True' but get 'None'

Tags: python

I have a simple Python script that recursively checks to see if a range of `n` numbers are factors of a number `x`.  If any of the numbers are not factors I return `False`, otherwise when the `n==1` I would like return `True`. However I keep returning `NoneType` and would appreciate suggestions on how to fix this.

```
#Function
def recursive_factor_test(x, n):
    if n==1:
        return True
    else: 
        if  x % n == 0:
            #print "passed {}".format(n)
            recursive_factor_test(x,n-1)
        else:
            return False

#Example Expecting False
print recursive_factor_test(5041,7)
>>False
#Example Expecting True
print recursive_factor_test(5040,7)
>>None
type(recursive_factor_test(5040,7))
>>NoneType
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't ever return the return value of the recursive call:

```
if  x % n == 0:
    #print "passed {}".format(n)
    return recursive_factor_test(x,n-1)
```

When you omit the `return` statement there, your function ends without a return statement, thus falling back to the default `None` return value.

With the `return` there, it works:

```
>>> print recursive_factor_test(5040,7)
True
```