# Working with calculating GCD - Python function return

Tags: python, python-2.7, return, return-value, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote a code which calculates the GCD of two numbers. The gcd of (24,12) is 12. The function `compute_gcd` computes the GCD and returns it which gets printed in the main function. However, the output is `none` when I return it to the main function and it is 12 when I print it in the `compute_gcd` function itself.

Where am I going wrong while returning the GCD?

```
def compute_gcd(a,b):
    if(b==0):
        return a             # Prints 12 if I replace with print a
    else:
        compute_gcd(b,a%b)

def main():
    a=24
    b=12 
    print compute_gcd(a,b)   # Prints none

main()
```

Comment: no return in `else` part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I expect 'True' but get 'None'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210646/i-expect-true-but-get-none)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put a `return` in the `else` branch. This works:

```
def compute_gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return compute_gcd(b,a%b)

def main():
    a=24
    b=12

    print compute_gcd(a,b)   # Prints 12

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ... you have to do a  `return` inside the `else` statement

```
def compute_gcd(a,b):
    if(b==0):
        return a
    else:
        return compute_gcd(b,a%b)

def main():
    a = 24
    b = 12

    print(compute_gcd(a,b))

main()
```

Answer (score -2):

Your else condition has no return hence output is none. If you change that to

```
else:
  return compute_gcd(b,a%b)
```

You'll get `12`.

Comment: How is that different from the answer that was posted 13 minutes ago?

Comment: I didn't see it as the answer tab was open. Downvotes, hell yes.