# If statement not firing

Tags: python

This code does a recursive bisection search for a character in a string.

When the `print` statements are not commented out, it seems to work well with the recursion and bisection, but the `if` statement that returns `True` does not seem to fire.

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    b = sorted(aStr)
    c = len(aStr)
    # print("string b " + str(b))
    # print("c " + str(c))
    # print("element middle: " + str(b[round(c/2)]))
    #print("char: " + str(char))
    #print(str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)]))
    if ((str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)]))): # this if statement does not seem to fire
        return True
    elif (c == 1 and char != str(b[round(c/2)])) or (c == 0 and char != "") :
        return False
        #print("false")
    else:

        #if str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)]):
         #   return True
           # print("true")
        if char > b[round(c/2)]:
            isIn(char, b[round(c/2):c])

        elif char < b[round(c/2)]:
            isIn(char, b[0:round(c/2)])
        else:
            return False
            #print('fales')
```

Comment: Make sure it's indented correctly

Comment: By "does not fire", do you mean that the condition `str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)])` does not evaluate to `True`? If indentation is the issue, this question is a moot point.

Comment: A dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210646/i-expect-true-but-get-none

Comment: Thank you. You are correct.  I did not have return before calling the recursive function.  I appreciate the feedback, and spent several hours troubleshooting.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result of each recursive call.

This is a very common mistake, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `round` in whatever that calculation is, as then you are using a `float` instead of an `int` as the index to the string.
use `int` instead:

```
str(b[int(c/2)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, has return before the recursive function calls:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
'''
char: a single character
aStr: an alphabetized string

returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
'''
b = sorted(aStr)
c = len(aStr)
# print("string b " + str(b))
# print("c " + str(c))
# print("element middle: " + str(b[round(c/2)]))
#print("char: " + str(char))
#print(str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)]))
if ((str(char) == str(b[int(c/2)]))): # this if statement does not seem to fire
    return True
elif (c == 1 and char != str(b[round(c/2)])) or (c == 0 and char != "") :
    return False
    #print("false")
else:

    #if str(char) == str(b[round(c/2)]):
     #   return True
       # print("true")
    if char > b[round(c/2)]:
        return isIn(char, b[round(c/2):c])

    elif char < b[round(c/2)]:
        return isIn(char, b[0:round(c/2)])
    else:
        return False
        #print('fales')
```

Comment: You're going to have to change all of the `round` statements to `int`. It didn't occur to me, that you would only change the first one. And while you are editing please alter the last statement to `#print('fails')`. Just a mild annoyance.