# Can print correct answer but can't return correct answer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm going through one of the early dataquest Python questions and here is the solution they have

```
def read_csv(filename):
    string_data = open(filename).read()
    string_list = string_data.split("\n")[1:]
    final_list = []

    for row in string_list:
        string_fields = row.split(",")
        int_fields = []
        for value in string_fields:
            int_fields.append(int(value))
        final_list.append(int_fields)
    return final_list
         cdc_list = read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv")
```

I went with a solution that involved recursion

```
data = open('US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv','r').read().split('\n')

def read_csv(dataset, header = False):
    if header == True:
        newdataset = dataset[1:len(dataset)]
        read_csv(newdataset)
    else:
        return_data = []
        for each in dataset:
            split_data = each.split(',')
            int_data = []
            for each in split_data:
                int_data.append(int(each))
            return_data.append(int_data)
        return(return_data)

cdc_list = read_csv(data, header = True)
```

My answer does not return any values for cdc_list.  However when I change the last line from

```
return(return_data)
```

to

```
print(return_data)
```

I'm able to see the correct results listed in the answer.

Comment: add `print(cdc_list)` at the end of your script, then try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I expect 'True' but get 'None'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210646/i-expect-true-but-get-none)

Answer (score 0):

The branch for `header == True` does not return any value, it only calls `read_csv()`. In that beginning block, try changing:

```
read_csv(newdataset)
```

to

```
return read_csv(newdataset)
```